# ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called (Databricks/Python)

Tags: python, pandas, databricks

I'm trying to setup a Pandas Dataframe for processing my data in Databricks. My data is imported from a file on my local machine as seen below:
[Snip of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pT7Y.png)

```
# Import packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

ownr = spark.read.format("csv").load("dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/directory/carsownr.csv")

# View the shape and data types
#print(ownr.shape)
print(ownr.dtypes);

#Setup Dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=ownr);
```

And when I run this, I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3703442649830271> in <module>
      1 #Setup Dataframes
----> 2 df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=ownr);
      3 df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=curr);

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    507                 )
    508             else:
--> 509                 raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")?
    510 
    511         NDFrame.__init__(self, mgr, fastpath=True)

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

I thought it may be because of my data, so I checked and all the fields are strings. Will I need to convert each column/field to the appropriate datatype for it to successfully be added in the dataframe?

I've searched the forums for similar error messages, but couldn't find a relevant one. I'd appreciate any help possible, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get Pandas Dataframe from the Spark Dataframe, then you need to use [toPandas function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toPandas.html) instead:

```py
df1 = ownr.toPandas()
```

Please also note that size of the Spark Dataframe should be small enough to fit into driver's memory.

Also, if you're looking for Pandas API for Spark, then look onto [Koalas library](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (Spark < 3.2, DBR < 10.0) that is also included into upcoming Spark 3.2 under name [Pandas API for Spark](https://databricks.com/blog/2021/10/04/pandas-api-on-upcoming-apache-spark-3-2.html) (DBR 10+) - in this case you'll get benefits of both Spark & Pandas

Comment: you need to rename before converting to Pandas

Comment: That worked, however I'm trying to rename the columns of the dataframe (since they're named as c1_0, c2_0, etc.) by using 
`df1a = df1.withColumnRenamed("_c0","Mark Link")`
 and now I'm getting this error 
`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'withColumnRenamed'`. Would you be able to explain why there's no columns?

Comment: Thank you so much!